# onMapReady function seems to not be called on android app

Tags: kotlin, google-maps

The map seems to be created but the marker does not get placed. Most questions relating to this problem seems to be missing `getmapasync` but th,s one seems to have it

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_dashboard)

    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as? SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
}
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    val sydney = LatLng(-33.852, 151.211)
    mMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions()
            .position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney")
    )
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END maps_marker_on_map_ready_add_marker]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your map fragment nested in a fragment?
If you are calling getMapAsync from a fragment that contains the actual map, you need to use **childFragmentManager** instead of **supportFragmentManager** to find the map

`(childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment).getMapAsync(this)`

Comment: Tnx for the comment it is indeed that way but i still cant figure out a way to implement childFragmentManager

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "implement childfragment manager"?

Comment: when i replace supportFragmentManager with childFragmentManager it cannot find a reference